# Nodemon не применяет изменения

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemon

Впервые решил попробовать **nodemon**. Установил его, запускаю проект. Делаю изменения, **nodemon** пишет `restarting due to changes...`, но изменения не применяются. Перезапускаю сервер вручную, изменения применяются.

**Nodemon** установлен локально, строка из ***package.json***

Подскажите, что может быть проблемой?

package.json

```html
{
  "name": "projectnone",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "nodemon -L ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "memory": "0.0.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "msnodesqlv8": "^0.8.3",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pug": "^2.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: `npm install nodemon --save-dev`  так устанавливал?

Comment: Да, не помогает.

Comment: попробуй установи  глобально и  покажи `package.json`

Comment: Добавил в изначальном вопросе. 

Установил глобально. Прошло всё ок, но выдал вот такую запись. npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\nod
emon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
)

+ nodemon@1.19.2
added 221 packages from 128 contributors in 29.184s

Comment: Не то написал, конечно же это package.json